# Why does the compiler not complain when the struct keyword is reused in a function, with a variable declaration?

Tags: c++, struct

Sorry about the vague question, I was unsure of how to be specific while being concise. I noticed the following behaviour when looking at a colleague's code, and I don't understand why the compiler (GCC 4.8.2) doesn't complain. Here is a trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct mystruct {
  int val;
};

int main()
{
  struct mystruct x; //What is the compiler doing here?

  /* Do something with x here */
  return(0);
}
```

How is the compiler treating the line `struct mystruct x;`? If it treated it as a declaration of some local struct called `mystruct` and initialisation of an instance called `x`, why am I allowed to treat `x` as an instance of the `mystruct` defined in the global scope?

My other thought was that it might be acting like a forward declaration, but I wasn't aware that one could declare an instance of a class at the same time as making a forward declaration. Is that simply what's happening here, though (and it's effectively doing nothing other than declaring the variable, since `mystruct` is already defined)?

Comment: The obvious answer for why the compiler doesn't complain is that it's valid code. The easiest answer for why is that it was valid (and often necessary) in C.

Comment: If you've ever seen code like this: `typedef struct { ... members ... } struct_name;` This is why. That form allows C programmers to declare struct objects without the struct keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't complain because there is nothing wrong with your code. You have done exactly what you have described. You have defined `x` to be a variable of type `mystruct`.

You may be unfamiliar with this form, but in C, it is the only way to declare variables to have a `struct` type. It's less common in C++ because the `struct` keyword was made optional in this context; however, C++ maintains compatibility with the traditional C syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As you suggested, I was unfamiliar with this form, having not used C much before.

Answer (score 3):

It's `c` syntax and as such valid for `c++`.

In `c` you would be required to use `typedef` if you wished to drop the `struct` keyword in the declaration.

Indeed if you declare the the `typedef`'d and untypedef'd name, you can initialise using either syntax.

e.g.

```
typedef struct mystruct {
  int val;
} mystruct;

int main()
{
  mystruct x;
  struct mystruct x2;

  /* Do something with x here */
  return(0);
}
```

For `c++` The use of `typedef` in the declaration of a `struct` is not required and so the use of `struct` in the declaration of an instance is optional, supported mainly for legacy reasons.

If you find yourself working on a cross C/C++ code base it will be useful to understand how both can play together happily like this.

Answer (score 1):

`struct mystruct` is synonymous with `mystruct`, assuming that such a struct has already been declared.

The word `struct` in this context is

- Completely **optional** in C++
- Potentially a readability aid, if you're prone to think that it's an `enum` or some other type
- A carryover from the C language, where it would have been required, given similar code.